# No address associated with hostnam : sonarque

Tags: dns, sonarqube, bitbucket

i'm trying to read a projet from bitbucket with sonarqube :
[image]

at he logs level :

```
INFO  web[AY3P4b2QrolR/txmAADE][o.s.a.c.b.BitbucketServerRestClient] Unable to contact Bitbucket server: git-xxxx.com: No address associated with hostname
sonarqube-ap | java.net.UnknownHostException: git-xxxx.com: No address associated with hostname
```